# api タグの使用方法を改善したい (webapi タグの提案)

Tags: 討議, タグ

[api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) というタグがあり、現状の説明では以下のようになっています。

> API (Application Programming Interface アプリケーションプログラミングインタフェース) は、
> プログラム間のインターフェイス仕様を定義したものです。

しかしここ最近の使われ方を見ると、例えば "[twitter](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) [api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api)" や "[facebook](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) [api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api)" など、いわゆる **Web API** の文脈で他のタグと併用する例も多く見かけます。

より具体的な名称のタグがあればそちらを優先すべきですし([facebook-graph-api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api), [stackexchange-api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-api))、個人的には単に「API」だと「Win32 API」などのイメージが強く、「Web API」は区別した方がいいんじゃないかなと思いました。

前述したような具体的なタグ名がまだ存在しない場合に、Web API の話題向けとして (英語版に存在する) [webapi](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webapi) タグの追加を提案しますが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: 参考までに [SOja交流会でちょっと話題にしました](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53612197#53612197)

Answer (score 5):

同意です。 SOja 交流会の流れを汲むと以下になるのかな、と思っています。

- [api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) : **非推奨**
- [webapi](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webapi) : ウェブサービスの API について
- [facebook-graph-api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api) など: 各サービスの API についての質問