# gpu タグはどのような質問に使うべきですか？

Tags: 討議, タグ, 話題の範囲

[gpu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu) というタグがあり、恐らくは「機械学習」関連で使われ始めたのかなと思われますが、現状ではタグ説明の記載が無いため、例えば「ディスプレイが映らない」などの純粋なハードウェア寄り？な質問にも割り当てられているのを見かけます。

- [Ubuntu20.04 LTSをインストールしてもブラックアウトする](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65996)
- [外付けGPU(eGPU)から出力できないディスプレイの解決方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73592)

一方で関連するタグに [ハードウェア](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%8f%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%82%a6%e3%82%a7%e3%82%a2) もありますが、前述のような "ハードウェア寄りな質問" への [gpu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu) タグの使用は現状のままで問題ありませんか？

**関連メタ投稿:**
[プログラムに関する質問か？そうでないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1546)

Comment: [api](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3353/4236)と同様に、質問者がタグにふさわしいと想像する質問と、閲覧者がタグから想像する質問との間に埋まらない溝があるように感じます。

Comment: 機械学習などはgpgpuに、ハードウェア寄りはハードウェアに、映像表示はそれぞれdirectxやopenglなどに、というのはどうでしょう