# service タグはどうあるべきか

Tags: 討議, タグ

[service](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) が作られています。日付を見る限りもともとはWebサービスの意味で作られたようですが、Windowsサービス、果てはUNIXデーモン（Linux方言でサービスと呼ぶから？）に関する話題まで含まれています。

明確な用途を定めるべきと思いますが、[api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) タグと同様に日本語で「サービス」と名の付く物のごった煮となりタグとしての意味を成さないのでいっそ削除するのもありではと考えています。どうあるべきでしょうか？

参考： [api タグの使用方法を改善したい (webapi タグの提案)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3353/4236)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

単に "service" というフレーズだけでは使われる範囲が広すぎるため、タグの役割である「質問を絞り込む」役目を果たせていないと思います。

[service](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) は削除 (または非推奨) とし、必要ならより具体的な名称のタグを使うべきだと思います。

- Linux なら既に [systemd](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemd) などがあります。
- Windows なら "windows-services" や "windowsサービス" が候補。
- "Webサービス" は現時点ではわざわざタグ付けするほどではないかなと感じます。

---

なお、参考までに英語版メタでも同様の議題が挙がっていますが、あちらではタグが割り当てられた質問が多すぎて結局整理が進められない状況に見えます。

[Out of [service]: Burninate? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361187)

整理をするなら早い段階でやってしまった方が良さそうです。

Comment: [tag:systemd]と[tag:windows-services]に分類しました。