# session タグの廃止

Tags: 討議, タグ

[session](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) タグが作られていますが、一般的な名称でありタグとして有効に機能するとは思えません。削除したほうがいいと思いますが、皆さんのご意見を伺いたいです。

参考： [service タグはどうあるべきか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3623/4236)、[api タグの使用方法を改善したい (webapi タグの提案)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3353/4236)

Answer (score 3):

個人的には、あっても別に良いかな程度に思っていました。プログラミングにおける「セッション」の意味はある程度絞られていますし、英語版の [session] タグ https://stackoverflow.com/tags/session/info と同じように使っていけそうな気がしています。